# IndexOf on string loaded from file - dotnet 5.0 half as fast as dotnetcore 3.1

Tags: .net, performance, indexof

I just discovered a file scanner of mine running very snappy in dotnetcore 3.1 but painfully slow on dotnet 5. It does things a little differently, but dotTrace points me to the IndexOf-method which I use.

I have boiled down a little test to this:

```
var str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("A text file of 125MB not containing hello in it");
start = DateTime.Now;
var result = str.IndexOf("hello");
var end = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Done in " + end.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds + " seconds");
```

Execution time **dotnet 3.1: 2 seconds**

Execution time **dotnet 5: 3.6 seconds**

It make no different whether I run in release or debug builds.

The difference is much worse in my real world case, but I think this still shows the problem.

What is important to notice is, that if I just create a string of the same size in-memory, like new string('a', size125mb) then it is very fast on both runtimes.

dotTrace shows that the case when using indexOf on the string in dotnet 5, the stack trace becomes this:

**Dotnet 5:**

```
System.String.IndexOf(String, Int32)
System.String.IndexOf(String, Int32, Int32, StringComparison)
System.Globalization.CompareInfo.IndexOf(String, String, Int32, Int32, IndexOf  •  4,327 msSystem.Globalization.CompareInfo.IndexOf(ReadOnlySpan, ReadOnlySpan, CompareOptions)
IcuIndexOfCore
```

**Dotnet 3.1:**

```
System.String.IndexOf(String, Int32)
System.String.IndexOf(String, Int32, Int32, StringComparison)
System.Globalization.CompareInfo.IndexOf(String, String, Int32, Int32, CompareOptions)
System.Globalization.CompareInfo.IndexOfCore(String, String, Int32, Int32, CompareOptions, Int32*)
System.Globalization.CompareInfo.FindString(UInt32, String, Int32, Int32, String, Int32, Int32, Int32*)
```

This actually shows different code executed in the two cases. The result is my scanner which runs through the entire loaded text runs on 5 seconds and finds 12k entries on dotnet 3.1, but it scans only 2 lines every second in dotnet 5.

Can anyone tell if this is just because I have to do things another way in dotnet 5 or did thay make a little mistake, causing this to be so slow on dotnet 5?

UPDATE 1:

Calling System.IO.File.ReadAllText seems to also be a lot slower on dotnet 5 (Its is the same file loaded in the two cases)

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I made another example that shows a x10 in performance diff:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
var str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("125mb txt file");
Console.WriteLine($"File loaded in {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds");
stopwatch.Restart();

int index = 0;
int foo = 0;
int counter = 0;
while(index < str.Length - 10)
{
    counter++;
    foo = str.IndexOf("AW()=DAW=)DA=)WDUAOWIDJAOWID", index, 10);
    index += 10;
    if (foo > 0)
       throw new Exception("Will never happen but dotnet does not know so it cannot remove the body as part of code optimization");
}

Console.WriteLine($"File iterated in {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds, " + counter + " iterations");
```

Output using **dotnet 5**:
[image]

Output using **dotnet 3.1**
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/globalization-icu

Comment: Thanks Hans. This discusses that the code has been fixed to behave equally in different environments. But does this mean, that we should all just accept the huge performance loss? Or could it be a bug in dotnet 5?

Comment: It documents how to get the old behavior back, of course you want to try that.

Comment: Hans: This seems to fix the performance differnece, thanks! Do you know if NLS is available when running the dotnet core app in a linux environment? I need to ensure that running code on my local windows machine will be identical to running it in our linux containers in the production environment.

Comment: @StephanMøller the article clearly says "On Unix, the APIs used International Components for Unicode (ICU)" and "Starting with .NET 5.0, developers have more control over which underlying library is used, enabling applications to avoid differences across platforms." so no significant performance difference should present on linux between 3.1 and 5.0

Comment: Guru: Yes, I understand that when using NLS explicitly, you get the same performance. My tests hows this as well. My question was regarding NLS being available in other environments than Windows. But I guess, you are stating, that this is indeed possible? :)

Comment: NLS is available on Windows only.  The linked article explains why this happened, they wanted to use the same library on both Unix and Windows.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. That is very useful to know. Guru just confused me then.